# Destructoring from function arguments

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I pass a single argument to a react functional component. What I need, is to destructore classes from props, but remain props intact, so I can refer to a props like `props.title` inside the component, but use classes without writing `props.classes`, just `classes`.

My idea was to do something like this, but it is not working:

```
const reactComponent = (props, { classes } = props) => { ... }
```

Is it possible to do it in javascrpit? Thank you.

Comment: "but it is not working" - explain?

Comment: in that case, 'classes' are undefined

Comment: [This is working!](http://jsbin.com/duvatocamu/edit?console)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry , just updated another correct way to achieve your goal:

```js
const reactComponent = function({classes}){
  console.log(arguments[0],classes);
};

reactComponent({ classes: "test" });
```

Comment: arrow functions dont even have `arguments`

Comment: yes , i was just aware of that , thank you for ringing a bell for me